# Procedure calling for updating bill amout

Tags: oracle

I have four tables with login details and scheme id details and rate for per byte and rate for per min values in each table. The table structure is as follows.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET;

CONNECTION_ID  LOGIN_ID LOGIN_DTTM                                    LOGOUT_DTTM                                        BYTES_CNT D M

          --------------      -------- -----------------------------------                -----------------------------------                         ----------        - -    
CON0000000001  USER1    01-SEP-08 10.00.00.000000 AM        01-SEP-08 12.15.00.000000 PM               100 N N    
CON0000000002  USER1    01-SEP-08 02.15.00.000000 AM        01-SEP-08 02.55.00.000000 AM               500 N N    
CON0000000003  USER1    10-SEP-08 02.15.00.000000 AM        10-SEP-08 04.15.00.000000 AM              1500 N N    
CON0000000004  USER1    30-SEP-08 10.00.00.000000 AM        30-SEP-08 11.35.00.000000 AM             10 N N    
CON0000000005  USER1    30-SEP-08 11.40.00.000000 AM        01-OCT-08 07.25.00.000000 AM               100 N N    
CON0000000006  USER1    03-OCT-08 08.45.00.000000 AM        05-OCT-08 07.25.00.000000 AM             12000 N N    
CON0000000007  USER1    16-SEP-08 09.15.00.000000 AM        17-SEP-08 09.15.00.000000 AM              1000 N N    
CON0000000008  USER1    24-SEP-08 02.15.00.000000 AM        24-SEP-08 11.50.00.000000 PM              1500 N N    
CON0000000009  USER2    01-SEP-08 10.00.00.000000 AM        01-SEP-08 12.15.00.000000 PM               100 N N    
CON0000000010  USER2    01-SEP-08 02.15.00.000000 PM        01-SEP-08 02.55.00.000000 PM               500 N N    
CON0000000011  USER2    10-SEP-08 02.15.00.000000 AM        10-SEP-08 04.15.00.000000 AM              1500 N N    
CON0000000012  USER2    30-SEP-08 10.00.00.000000 PM        30-SEP-08 11.35.00.000000 PM             10 N N    
CON0000000013  USER2    30-SEP-08 11.40.00.000000 PM        01-OCT-08 07.25.00.000000 AM               100 N N    
CON0000000014  USER2    03-OCT-08 08.45.00.000000 AM        05-OCT-08 07.25.00.000000 AM             12000 N N    
CON0000000015  USER2    16-SEP-08 09.15.00.000000 AM        17-SEP-08 09.15.00.000000 AM              1000 N N    
CON0000000016  USER2    24-SEP-08 02.15.00.000000 AM        24-SEP-08 11.50.00.000000 PM              1500 N N    
CON0000000017  USER3    01-SEP-08 10.00.00.000000 AM        01-SEP-08 12.15.00.000000 PM               100 N N    
CON0000000018  USER3    01-SEP-08 02.15.00.000000 PM        01-SEP-08 02.55.00.000000 PM               500 N N    
CON0000000019  USER3    10-SEP-08 02.15.00.000000 AM        10-SEP-08 04.15.00.000000 AM              1500 N N    
CON0000000020  USER3    30-SEP-08 10.00.00.000000 PM        30-SEP-08 11.35.00.000000 PM             10 N N    
CON0000000021  USER3    30-SEP-08 11.40.00.000000 PM        01-OCT-08 07.25.00.000000 AM               100 N N    
CON0000000022  USER3    03-OCT-08 08.45.00.000000 AM        05-OCT-08 07.25.00.000000 AM             12000 N N    
CON0000000023  USER3    16-SEP-08 09.15.00.000000 AM        17-SEP-08 09.15.00.000000 AM              1000 N N    
CON0000000024  USER3    24-SEP-08 02.15.00.000000 AM        24-SEP-08 11.50.00.000000 PM              1500 N N    
CON0000000025  USER4    01-SEP-08 10.00.00.000000 AM        01-SEP-08 12.15.00.000000 PM               100 N N    
CON0000000026  USER4    01-SEP-08 02.15.00.000000 PM        01-SEP-08 02.55.00.000000 PM               500 N N   
CON0000000027  USER4    01-SEP-08 02.15.00.000000 AM        01-SEP-08 04.15.00.000000 AM              1500 N N    
CON0000000028  USER4    30-SEP-08 10.00.00.000000 PM        30-SEP-08 11.35.00.000000 PM             10 N N    
CON0000000029  USER4    30-SEP-08 11.40.00.000000 PM        01-OCT-08 07.25.00.000000 AM               100 N N    
CON0000000030  USER4    03-OCT-08 08.45.00.000000 AM        05-OCT-08 07.25.00.000000 AM             12000 N N    
CON0000000031  USER4    16-SEP-08 09.15.00.000000 AM        17-SEP-08 09.15.00.000000 AM              1000 N N    
CON0000000032  USER4    24-SEP-08 02.15.00.000000 AM        24-SEP-08 11.50.00.000000 PM              1500 N N    
CON0000000033  USER1    24-SEP-07 02.15.00.000000 AM        24-SEP-07 05.15.00.000000 AM               122 N N    
CON0000000034  USER1    25-SEP-07 02.15.00.000000 AM        26-SEP-07 02.15.00.000000 AM               544 N N    
CON0000000035  USER2    25-SEP-07 02.15.00.000000 AM        26-SEP-07 02.15.00.000000 AM               355 N N    
CON0000000036  USER3    24-SEP-07 02.15.00.000000 AM        24-SEP-07 05.15.00.000000 AM               100 N N    
CON0000000037  USER3    25-SEP-07 02.15.00.000000 AM        26-SEP-07 02.15.00.000000 AM             10 N N    
CON0000000038  USER3    25-DEC-07 02.15.00.000000 AM        25-DEC-07 06.15.00.000000 AM              1000 N N


SQL> SELECT * FROM ISBS_CUSTOMER_MST;

CUST_ID        LOGIN_ID CUST_NM         CUST_ADDR

-------------- -------- --------------- ------------------------------------------------------

CUST0000000001 USER1    User Login ID 1 143/1 Uthamar Gandhi Salai, Nungambakkam, Chennai - 34    
CUST0000000002 USER2    User Login ID 2 143/2 Uthamar Gandhi Salai, Nungambakkam, Chennai - 34    
CUST0000000003 USER3    User Login ID 3 143/3 Uthamar Gandhi Salai, Nungambakkam, Chennai - 34    
CUST0000000004 USER4    User Login ID 4 143/4 Uthamar Gandhi Salai, Nungambakkam, Chennai - 34


SELECT * FROM ISBS_CUSTOMER_SCHEME_XREF;


CUST_SCHEME_XR CUST_ID      SCHEME_DETAIL_ID EFFECTIVE_DTTM

-------------- -------------- ---------------- ----------------------------
CXR0000000001  CUST0000000001 SCD0000000001 01-SEP-08 12.01.00.000000 AM
CXR0000000002  CUST0000000002 SCD0000000001 01-SEP-08 12.01.00.000000 AM
CXR0000000003  CUST0000000002 SCD0000000002 24-SEP-08 03.10.00.000000 AM
CXR0000000004  CUST0000000003 SCD0000000001 01-SEP-08 12.01.00.000000 AM
CXR0000000005  CUST0000000003 SCD0000000003 16-SEP-08 10.01.00.000000 AM
CXR0000000006  CUST0000000004 SCD0000000002 01-SEP-08 12.01.00.000000 AM
CXR0000000007  CUST0000000004 SCD0000000004 10-SEP-08 03.01.00.000000 AM
CXR0000000008  CUST0000000004 SCD0000000005 24-SEP-08 11.15.00.000000 AM

SELECT * FROM ISBS_BYTE_SCHEME_DET;


SCHEME_DETAIL_ID SCHEME_ID      RATE_PER_BYTE_AMT

---------------- -------------- -----------------
SCD0000000005   SCH0000000003               .001
SCD0000000006   SCH0000000003           

.0015

 SELECT * FROM ISBS_TIME_SCHEME_DET;


SCHEME_DETAIL_ID  IDX SCHEME_ID     RATE_EFFECTIVE_FROM_TM RATE_EFFECTIVE_TO_TM RATE_PER_MIN_AMT

---------------- ---- -------------- ---------------------- -------------------- ----------------
SCD0000000003       1 SCH0000000002  2200                   0400                            .1
SCD0000000003       2 SCH0000000002  0400                   1000                            .2
SCD0000000003       3 SCH0000000002  1000                   1800                            .5
SCD0000000003       4 SCH0000000002  1800                   2200                            .3
SCD0000000004       1 SCH0000000002  2200                   0400                            .05
SCD0000000004       2 SCH0000000002  0400                   1000                            .25
SCD0000000004       3 SCH0000000002  1000                   1800                            .35
SCD0000000004       4 SCH0000000002  1800                   2200                            .3
```

I have created a procedure which gets the date as input and should calculate the daily bill amount based on the bytes count and the minutes of login. The calculated values should be updated in ISBS_DAILY_BILLING_REP if the input date exists in the table else it has to be inserted as a new row. But I am not getting the desired output. So please help me solve the issue. I am also attaching the procedure along with this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ISBS_DAILY_BILL_SP (p_date IN NUMBER)    
AS    
    v_rate_per_byte_amt    NUMBER;    
    v_scheme_detail_id      VARCHAR2(30);    
    v_bill_amt                     VARCHAR2(40);    
    v_rate_per_min_amt    VARCHAR2(40);    
    v_bill                            VARCHAR2(30);    
    v_login                         VARCHAR2(30);    
    v_logout                       VARCHAR2(30);

    CURSOR ISBS_BYTES    
    IS    
    SELECT s.CONNECTION_ID    
         , s.LOGIN_DTTM    
         , s.LOGOUT_DTTM    
         , s.BYTES_CNT    
         , c.CUST_ID    
         , r.SCHEME_DETAIL_ID    
      FROM ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET s    
         , ISBS_CUSTOMER_MST c    
         , ISBS_CUSTOMER_SCHEME_XREF r    
         , ISBS_BYTE_SCHEME_DET b    
     WHERE s.LOGIN_ID = c.LOGIN_ID    
       AND c.CUST_ID = r.CUST_ID    
       AND r.SCHEME_DETAIL_ID = b.SCHEME_DETAIL_ID    
       AND TO_CHAR(LOGIN_DTTM, 'DD') = p_date;    

    CURSOR ISBS_MINS    
    IS    
    SELECT s.CONNECTION_ID    
         , s.LOGIN_DTTM    
         , s.LOGOUT_DTTM    
         , c.CUST_ID    
         , r.SCHEME_DETAIL_ID    
         , t.RATE_PER_MIN_AMT    
      FROM ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET s    
         , ISBS_CUSTOMER_MST c    
         , ISBS_CUSTOMER_SCHEME_XREF r    
         , ISBS_TIME_SCHEME_DET t    
     WHERE s.LOGIN_ID = c.LOGIN_ID    
       AND c.CUST_ID = r.CUST_ID    
       AND r.SCHEME_DETAIL_ID = t.SCHEME_DETAIL_ID    
          AND TO_CHAR(s.LOGIN_DTTM, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN t.RATE_EFFECTIVE_FROM_TM AND t.RATE_EFFECTIVE_TO_TM    
       AND TO_CHAR(s.LOGOUT_DTTM, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN t.RATE_EFFECTIVE_FROM_TM AND t.RATE_EFFECTIVE_TO_TM    
       AND TO_CHAR(LOGIN_DTTM, 'DD') = p_date;

BEGIN

    FOR i IN ISBS_BYTES    
    LOOP

    SELECT RATE_PER_BYTE_AMT INTO v_rate_per_byte_amt    
      FROM ISBS_BYTE_SCHEME_DET    
     WHERE SCHEME_DETAIL_ID = i.SCHEME_DETAIL_ID;

    v_bill_amt := i.BYTES_CNT * v_rate_per_byte_amt;

 IF TO_CHAR(i.LOGIN_DTTM, 'DD') = p_date THEN

    UPDATE ISBS_DAILY_BILLING_REP    
       SET BILLING_AMT = v_bill_amt 
     WHERE TO_CHAR(BILL_FOR_DT, 'DD') = p_date    
       AND CUST_ID = i.CUST_ID;

    ELSE

    INSERT INTO ISBS_DAILY_BILLING_REP (CUST_ID, BILL_FOR_DT, BILLING_AMT, BILL_GEN_DTTM)    
                                VALUES (i.CUST_ID, i.LOGIN_DTTM, v_bill_amt, i.LOGOUT_DTTM);

    END IF;

    END LOOP;



    FOR j IN ISBS_MINS    
    LOOP

    SELECT TO_CHAR(LOGIN_DTTM, 'HHMI'), TO_CHAR(LOGOUT_DTTM, 'HHMI') INTO v_login, v_logout    
      FROM ISBS_SESSION_CONNECTION_DET    
     WHERE CONNECTION_ID = j.CONNECTION_ID;

    v_rate_per_min_amt := v_logout - v_login;    
    v_bill := v_rate_per_min_amt * j.RATE_PER_MIN_AMT;    

    UPDATE ISBS_DAILY_BILLING_REP    
       SET BILLING_AMT = BILLING_AMT + v_bill    
         , BILL_FOR_DT = j.LOGIN_DTTM    
         , BILL_GEN_DTTM = j.LOGOUT_DTTM    
     WHERE CUST_ID = j.CUST_ID    
       AND TO_CHAR(BILL_FOR_DT, 'DD') = p_date;    

    INSERT INTO ISBS_DAILY_BILLING_REP (CUST_ID, BILL_FOR_DT, BILLING_AMT, BILL_GEN_DTTM)    
                                VALUES (j.CUST_ID, j.LOGIN_DTTM, v_bill, j.LOGOUT_DTTM);

    END LOOP;

END ISBS_DAILY_BILL_SP;

/
```

Comment: Do you think SO is a coding service? Please narrow down the question to your actual problem.

Comment: What do you mean by not getting desired output?What is the desired output?

Comment: Kaushik Nayak The desired output is to update the table with the newly calculated amount if the date and customer exists else it should be inserted as a new row as a single row. But i am getting more than one row insertion.